# Inner Query for lookup relationship is not working

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying the below inner query for lookup relationship on Account created for `detail__c` : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WuYI.jpg

```
List<Account> detailObj = new List<Account>([select id, (select id from detail__c) from Account]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lookup is on the Account object looking up to the Detail object. If you're querying accounts, then the Detail records will be parents of the accounts. You can retrieve the parent data like this:

`List <Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Detail__r.Id, Detail__r.Name, Detail__r.Custom_Field__c FROM Account];`;

If you were to query Detail records with their Accounts as children, then you would use the child relationship name:

`List <Detail__c> details = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Detail__r) FROM Detail__c];`

You should rename the child relationship name to be `accounts` and this whole thing will make more sense.

Comment: It is not working with detail__r, I am getting the below error

Comment: Didn't understand relationship 'detail__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Did you check the child relationship name on the lookup field?

Comment: I can see the child relationship name here - http://snag.gy/T2Kyq.jpg. But still trying query with combination of detail, detail_c, detail__r does not work.

Comment: Can you please check the field level security for the lookup field and make sure it's visible to the profile?

Comment: the field is visible for the system administrator - http://snag.gy/Pu4fl.jpg

Comment: List<Account> masterObj = new List<Account>([select id, (select id from detail__r) from Account]); - is the query I am trying.

Comment: does salesforce really works with inner query for the lookup fields ? I cant figure out where I am missing here :(

Comment: Just saw the screenshot again and I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have a small doubt..if you could please help :(  -- If the lookup field is created on account then should the child relationship name be Accounts ? When I try creating a new lookup field also on Account the child relationship name comes as Accounts (which according to me should be details). Why so ?

Answer (score 1):

As Bachovski points out you need to discover what the Child Relationship Name is. For help with relationship queries take a look at the SOQL and SOSL Reference PDF found [here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_soql_sosl.pdf). On page 55 you will find the following image that shows you where to find the name:
[image: Relationship]

> Notice that the Child Relationship Name (parent to child) is the
>   plural form of the child object name, in this case Daughters.

Since it is modifiable, it may have been modified from it's default plural form of the child object name, so you need to verify the name.

Answer (score 0):

You will see a child relationship name if you try to edit the Detail__c field.

Parent-Child SOQL:

```
List<Account> detailobj= New List<Account>[select Id, Name,(Select Id, Name from details_r (ChilRelationshipname)) from Account];
```